# javascript shopping cart calculator

Tags: javascript

Hi Everyone I'm trying to make a shopping cart calculator using javascript for a school project. Simply adding up a subtotal depending on how many of each item is entered. I've spent a few hours trying to figure this out, but I cannot. What is wrong with my  method and how can I fix it? Please help me out and thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
function calc()
{
var priceBooks = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceBook").innerHTML);    
var pricePens = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pricePens").innerHTML);
var pricePencils = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pricePencils").innerHTML);
var priceHighlighter = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceHighlighter").innerHTML);
var priceBatteries = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceBatteries").innerHTML);

var book = parseInt(document.getElementById("book").value);
var pen = parseInt(document.getElementById("pen").value);
var pencil = parseInt(document.getElementById("pencil").value);
var highlighter = parseInt(document.getElementById("highlighter").value);
var batteries = parseInt(document.getElementById("batteries").value);

var subTotal = document.getElementById("subT");

if(book < 0 || pen < 0 || pencil < 0 || highlighter < 0 || batteries < 0)
{
    subTotal.innerHTML="Invalid quantity. Please do not use negative numbers."; 
}
else
{
    var bookTotal = priceBooks*book;
    var penTotal = pricePens*pen;
    var pencilTotal = pricePencils*pencil;
    var highlighterTotal = priceHighlighter*highlighter;
    var batteryTotal = priceBatteries*batteries;
    var subT = bookTotal+penTotal+pencilTotal+highlighterTotal+batteryTotal;
    subTotal.innerHTML = subT;
}
}
```

Here is the full site:
http://www.albany.edu/~rf124561/Final/Final.html

---

Edit: Thank you for all the suggestions. It seems that it wants to work now but everytime I click the button to calculate it refreshes the page. Other than that Thank you everyone :)

Comment: I don't see a question?

Comment: You'll want to use parseFloat instead of parseInt on the prices.  When you use parseInt, you'll want to add a radix. Your id for the highliter price doesn't match your html.  You really should use the web inspector and step through your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your pen highlighter has the wrong ID in the JS
Where is subT defined? You're using it to hold a value, and then it's magically an element as well. I think you need to uncomment that subtotal line, and use that for your innerHTML statements. Report back after you've fixed those things if that doesn't solve it.

EDIT: Oh, and you're using parseInt on float value. That will also mess you up when things get working. Use parseFloat.

Comment: I have made your suggestions thank you, it seems that it wants to work now but every time I click the button it refreshes the page. :/

Comment: It was already doing that for me. Please update the link you provided so I can work with the changes.

Comment: Add type="button" to the button to make it stop refreshing, then it works. Then you'll just need to debug why the total isn't working, which you'll just need to double check your logic to do.

Comment: @Rafael, have you gotten this to work?

Comment: @Rafael, if my answer was a solution, please click the checkmark below the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

uncomment

```
var subTotal = document.getElementById("subT");
```

change these lines:

```
subT.innerHTML="Invalid quantity. Please do not use negative numbers."; 
subT.innerHTML = subT;
```

into

```
subTotal.innerHTML="Invalid quantity. Please do not use negative numbers."; 
subTotal.innerHTML = subT;
```

and, what David said, use parseFloat in case of floats :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong..

But `pricePenHighlighter` doesn't seem to be an id meaning that this line:

```
var priceHighlighter = parseInt(document.getElementById("pricePenHighlighter").innerHTML);
```

will result something..  well probably `NaN`? and either the function will return or it will at least break your result.

I believe I saw a `priceHighlighter` which might be what you meant?